# Wordpress Images upload with good quality issuse

Tags: wordpress

I have faced a problem regarding WordPress Images, I want to upload good quality images on a WordPress website with image optimization. When I'm trying to reduce the size of the image from MB's to KB's it quality is ultimately decreased. I want to upload images less than 100 KB files without reducing the quality of the image. So Is there any solution in which I can upload the images within Good quality and with minimum filesize?
I'll be thankful If anyone helps me regarding this issue.
Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: You can use https://tinypng.com/ website to compress image size without losing quality of image. and also use plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tiny-compress-images/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tinyjpg.com or smash plugin to shrink the images. This will help you to optimize your website.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am already using the Smash Plugin. Now I will also use  tinyjpg.com to compress the files.